# Show that $\frac{\pi}{4} = 1 − \frac13 +\frac15 −\frac17 + \cdots$ using Fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, pi

Consider the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{2}$, defined over the interval $[0, 2\pi]$. Show that $\frac{\pi}{4} = 1 − \frac13 +\frac15 −\frac17 + \cdots$.

Comment: I think you might have typoed. The function $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ does not have a period.

Comment: Assuming the case that it has a period 2pi

Comment: So do you mean: $$f(x)=\pi\left(\frac{x}{2\pi}-\bigg\lfloor\frac{x}{2\pi}\bigg\rfloor\right)$$

Comment: You can keep the function to be  f(x) = x/2. This is one of the questions asked in my quiz yesterday. I think you would know better what we can do with this and how this can be shown.

Comment: Hint: You must have done Fourier series.

Comment: @IanMiller: It's the typical thing about Fourier series. Either you consider $f$ to be defined only on $[0, 2\pi]$, or you extend it by periodicity to the whole $\Bbb R$. The question is slightly misformulated, but should be clear to anybody knowing about Fourier series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to expand $y=x/2$ as a Fourier series:
$$
{x\over2}=\sin (x)-\frac{1}{2} \sin (2 x)+\frac{1}{3} \sin (3 x)-\frac{1}{4} \sin (4x)+\frac{1}{5} \sin (5 x)+\ldots
$$
and put here $x=\pi/2$.

Comment: Keeping the period to be 2pi?
Can you explain it a bit?

Comment: As a matter of fact the question is not well formulated: $f(x)$ should be defined as $x/2$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and extended by periodicity for the other values of $x$.